# Search for topics with specific message

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

My question is the following:

Suppose I have a list of topics and each topic publishes a message of type messageType.

Is there a command that allows me output the all messageTypes that are currently being published?

I know "rostopic info -topicname" will give me information as well as the message a specific topic outputs. Is there a wildcard like rostopic info * that lets me see all the messages that are currently being published?

Thank you in advance,

Panos.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209081/search-for-topics-with-specific-message/) by [panos](https://answers.ros.org/users/22350/panos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2015-05-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of a built-in command that does exactly what you want, but you could always combine `rostopic` outputs using standard command line tools (piping, xargs, etc.).

For example, to get the detailed information about every topic, you could run:

```
rostopic list |xargs -n 1 rostopic info
```

Or you could combine with grep:

```
rostopic list |grep robot |xargs -n 1 rostopic info
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to avoid calling command line binaries (which can become tricky depending on the state of your shell / system), you should probably take a look at the [ROS Master API](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Master_API). I think especially `getTopicTypes(..)` and `getSystemState(..)` should be helpful.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1